# With Wireshark we can capture a datagram originated on the same computer that has the loopback address as a destination

Tags: wireshark

Why in WireShark we can capture a datagram with an IP address from the link-local type and not a datagram originated on the same computer that has the loopback address as a destination???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Wireshark Capture Setup - Loopback](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) .